# Is $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\overline{F}(x)=0$?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, expectation, distribution-tails

With partial integration I wanted to prove that for non-negative random variable with CDF F(x) holds
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\overline{F}(x)dx=E[X].
$$
Here is $\overline{F}(x)= 1-F(x)$. I got this far
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\overline{F}(x)dx=\lim_{x\to{\infty}} x\overline{F}(x)-0+\underbrace{\int_{0}^\infty xf(x)dx}_{E[X]}.
$$

But now I don't know hot to calcute the upper limit.

Does anyone have a clue how to prove this?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Remember that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$ for any CDF $F(X)$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} \overline{F}(x) = 0$.

Comment: @ZainPatel I know that. What I don't know if $\overline{F}(x)$ is converging faster than $x$ to 0 as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: perhaps L'Hopital might be useful here?

Comment: is this useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201577/show-mathbbex-int-0-infty-1-f-xx-dx-for-a-continuous-random?rq=1

Comment: @ZainPatel I saw that answer. But I was wondering if the proof can be done as written above.

Comment: Kyoto, what about this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354942/proof-that-ex-infty-entails-lim-n-to-inftyn-prx-ge-n-0?rq=1 (for the discrete version, perhaps you can adapt this to the continuous case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\bar{F}(x) = 1- \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X>x)$, we have

$$x \bar{F}(x) = \int_{\{X>x\}} x \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \int_{\{X>x\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}$$

for any $x>0$. If $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$, then we can let $x \to \infty$ using the dominated convergence theorem to conclude

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \bar{F}(x)=0.$$

If $\mathbb{E}(X)=\infty$ then $x \bar{F}(x)$ does not necessarily converge to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ (consider for example a random variable with Cauchy distribution).

A remark concerning your proof: Mind that you have to assume the existence of a density, i.e. your proof works only for random variables which have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks @saz !